# android get number only keyboard

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a app in flash cs 6. I want to know if it is possible to get numbers only soft keyboard and is it possible to replace enter key to done key and when done key is pressed I want the virtual keyboard gets down.

Answer (score 1):

Put this on the edit text for which you want to open the number only key board

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Also add `android:singleLine="true"` for the EditText. This will replace the enter with Next (for all edittexts except the last one) and Done (for the last one).

Comment: please note tags other than `android`

Comment: is above code for flash ? I'm doing my project in flash cs6.